# Keep only rows of matrix with largest elements within intervals

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix in which the right-most elements are repeated YYYYMMDD dates in descending order, for example:

```
      40        1630        1711    20140326
     169         700         950    20140326
      40        1630        1711    20140326
     169         700         950    20140327
      40        1630        1711    20140327
     169         700         950    20140327
      40        1630        1711    20140327
     169         700         950    20140328
      40        1630        1711    20140328
     169         700         950    20140328
      40        1630        1711    20140328
    3049         700         950    20140331
      40        1630        1711    20140331
    3049         700         950    20140331
      40        1630        1711    20140331
     169         700         950    20140401
      40        1630        1711    20140401
     169         700         950    20140401
      40        1630        1711    20140401
     169         700         950    20140402
      40        1630        1711    20140402
```

Within each date, I want to keep only the row that corresponds to the largest element
in the leftmost column. So I would like to produce a new matrix:

```
     169         700         950    20140326
     169         700         950    20140327
     169         700         950    20140328
    3049         700         950    20140331
     169         700         950    20140402
```

What is the best way to do this?

Ideas: use diff to find indices of when date changes, and use a for loop to cycle through intervals using max to find the correct rows. any solution without a for loop?

Comment: Only by including that last line (the edit), you improved the quality of this question drastically. Without it, it doesn't seem like you have given this any thought at all. Try to remember always doing this in future questions, as otherwise they might get closed or downvoted pretty fast. Including your attempted code is even better. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to first [sort the rows](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) based on the first column, thereafter find the first [unique dates](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) based on the last:

```
B = sortrows(A)
[~, ia] = unique(B(:,4))
B(ia,:)
ans =
        169        700        950   20140326
        169        700        950   20140327
        169        700        950   20140328
       3049        700        950   20140331
        169        700        950   20140401
        169        700        950   20140402
```

Comment: Ok :-) I only tested it online, didn't have to flip it there (strange). Might  be `-sortrows(-A)` is faster (but I'm not sure). Glad I could help :-)

Comment: @Divakar, thanks =) Did a rollback to the first version, which seems to be correct after all. I changed it blindly after OP's comment.

Comment: @RobertP. haha it happens! Well I implemented this with some `bsxfun` approach but that was a bit longer than yours. Kool idea with the `sortrows`!